# Preg Match to get Table Names from SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, regex

I'm trying to grab the table names from my sql file for an upgrade script but I have something incorrect.

Lines in my SQL file that have the names are the CREATE TABLE lines:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ocx_category` (
```

In the `preg_match_all` statement I'm using this regex:

```
preg_match_all('#create\s*table\s*`(\w[\w\d]*)`#i', $sql, $table);
```

But all `$table` ends up with:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You don't need both `\w` and `\d`, since `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscore.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
CREATE TABLE.*`(\w+)`
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qS0nS8/5)**

By the way, your regex is `(\w[\w\d]*)` you don't need `[\w\d]` since `\w` includes `\d`. So, basically what I do is to shorten your regex to `\w+` and include whatever string you have after "create table"

[image]

Comment: Here we go `preg_match_all('#create\s*table\s*if\s*not\s*exists\s*`(\w+)`#i', $sql, $table);`

Works great thanks for the help.

Comment: @VinceKronlein glad to help you my friend. Thanks for the tick and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
...table\s*`(\w[...
        ^^^^--incorrect
```

`table` followed by zero or more whitespace chars (`\s*`) followed by a backtick (`` ` ``). You're not allowing for the "IF NOT EXISTS" portion.

Comment: `\s+` instead of `\s*` because at least one space must be there.